# How to display Date in this format using Javascript Jan 01, 2012

Tags: javascript, date

There is a date say

```
var x = new Date("2012-01-01");
```

I need to display it in this format -  Jan 01, 2012
How can I do that?

```
x.toDateString()
```

returns Sun Jan 01 2012"

Comment: Which date library are you using? `toDate` doesn’t exist in JavaScript, and neither does a constructor called `date`.

Comment: Use http://momentjs.com/

Comment: @false he is using the [data object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Comment: Don't pass date strings to the Date constructor, the results are known to be inconsistent across even the most modern browsers. Manually parse the parts and create a date object.

Comment: @user3669154: I’m not clicking on a W3Schools link, but if the edit was anything to go by, `date` and `toDate` really don’t exist.

Comment: @false How about a [MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) instead?

Comment: @user3669154: Great, thank you. `toDate` really doesn’t exist, though, and `Date` is capitalized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've always done it like this:

```
var monthsArr = new Array("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");
var day = x.getDate();
var month = x.getMonth();
var year = x.getFullYear();

var date = monthsArr[month]+" "+day+", "+year;
```

There might be a better way to do it that I don't know of, but this should get you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

User3669154 has the answer you need for formatting (though it would be better as a function), however you should not pass date strings to the Date constructor. Manually parse strings to create a Date object:

```
// Create a date object given yyyy-mm-dd
function parseYMD(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D+/);
  return new Date(b[0], --b[1], b[2]);
}
```

Note that a string like "2012-01-01" will be treated as UTC in standards compliant browsers but as local in others that conform to the ISO 8601 standard and ECMA-262 ed 6 draft. So if you are in a place that has a timezone of UTC-05:00, then:

```
new Date('2012-01-01')
```

will create a Date object with a time equivalent to 2012-01-01T00:00:00Z (i.e. 2011-12-31 19:00:00 local) in some browsers but 2012-01-01T05:00:00Z (i.e. 2012-01-01 00:00:00 local) in others.